one_hot from Keras producing the same value for different words
I am using one_hot function from keras to convert my words into numbers. But for some reason it is producing the same number for different words. In the code below you can see 48 is used for "amazing" but 48 is also used for "too". Why is that?
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot

reviews = ['nice food',
        'amazing restaurant',
        'too good',
        'just loved it!',
        'will go again',
        'horrible food',
        'never go there',
        'poor service',
        'poor quality',
        'needs improvement']

# convert to ont hot vector 
encoded_reviews = [one_hot(d, vocab_size) for d in reviews]

When I print encoded_reviews it shows:
[[13, 12],
 [48, 44],
 [48, 19],
 [38, 28, 46],
 [13, 29, 19],
 [46, 12],
 [19, 29, 4],
 [18, 38],
 [18, 35],
 [42, 7]]


Does this answer your question? keras pre-processing of text using one_hot class

Thanks! But if different words can produce same hash and I don't want to alter my vocab size then words like "bad" and "amazing" can produce the same one_hot encoding and can result in a completely different result.

I think that is to be expected based on the docs. All hash functions are inherently prone to collisions. From that answer - The probability of a collision is in relation to the dimension of the hashing space and the number of distinct objects. Given that, reducing the hashing space (vocab_size) increases the probability of collisions leading to different words having the same hash

Since one-hot encoding uses hashing, there is a probability of collisions
where different words are assigned the same index. The probability of
collision increases with the vocabulary size. However, a larger vocabulary can
also improve the representation of distinct words. Jason Brownlee suggests
using a vocabulary size about 25% larger than the number of unique words to
balance collision risk and representation quality. By increasing the
vocabulary size in the provided code, the numerical representation of the text
changes, resulting in different encoded values.Please refer this gist
